# MVC requests interfering with calls to AutoQuery-enabled ServiceStack API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have an MVC solution that contains a ServiceStack API alongside an MVC UI that makes calls to the API services. Some of those services are AutoQuery `GET` endpoints, and I'm running into a problem where the ServiceStack service picks up posted form values or unrelated querystring values and throws argument errors when I call the services.

I've tried a number of ways of calling the services:

```
using (var fooSvc = new HostContext.ResolveService<FooService>(HttpContext))
{
    var foos = (QueryResponse<Foo>)fooSvc.Get(new Foos());
    // Do stuff here
}
```

No dice. Posted form values screw it up and I get a `System.FormatException` saying `Input string was not in a correct format` on this line in my service:

```
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());
```

So I tried:

```
var foos = (QueryResponse<Foo>)HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(new Foos());
```

In this case, I get a `System.NotImplementedException` saying it couldn't find a `Post(Foos)` or `Any(Foos)` (the call in question is a `GET`).

I'm sure I'm missing something simply. Mythz, got another rescue for me?

**EDIT:** I hand-typed that code...the initial block had `AutoQuery` when I meant `QueryResponse`...

**EDIT 2:** Here is the general structure of my AutoQuery services. These are all `GET` on the service because those endpoints also need to support `POST` to create a resource. For example, I might have the URI at `http:/service.com/api/users` and want to be able to `GET` with AutoQuery or `POST` to create a new user.

```
[Authenticate]
public class UsersService : Service
{
    public IAutoQuery AutoQuery { get; set; }

    public object Get(Users request)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());

        // Here I add some other conditions to the query object to filter results based on the user's role, etc.

        return AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
    }

    [RequiredRole("Admin")]
    public object Post(CreateUser request)
    {
        var user = request.ConvertTo<User>();
        Db.Save(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a Service you're just calling a method directly on the target instance. What does the method returns? It's unlikely it's `AutoQuery<Foo>` since it's not a valid type in ServiceStack:

```
var foos = (AutoQuery<Foo>)fooSvc.Get(new Foos());
```

If you're getting a FormatException check the QueryString param that's causing it. Something in the Request is incompatible with the AutoQuery field.

Did you create the method yourself because AutoQuery generates services using the `Any` method so that it can be called by any verb. If it's a Custom Service change it to `Any`.

Otherwise you can Execute the method with the current HTTP Request with:

```
var foos = (QueryResponse<Foo>)HostContext.ServiceController
    .Execute(new Foos(), HttpContext.ToRequest());
```

You can also override what Verb that gets executed with:

```
var req = HttpContext.ToRequest();
req.Items[Keywords.InvokeVerb] = "GET";
var foos = (QueryResponse<Foo>)HostContext.ServiceController
    .Execute(new Foos(), req);
```

#### [Custom AutoQuery Implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#custom-autoquery-implementations)

If you have conflicted fields trying to forward the request I would just change them to use fields that don't conflict with AutoQuery request. But if you still want to continue using the conflicted fields you can create a 
[Custom AutoQuery Implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#custom-autoquery-implementations) that removes it from the AutoQuery services instead, e.g:

```
public class UsersService : Service
{
    public IAutoQuery AutoQuery { get; set; }

    public object Any(Users request)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> args = Request.GetRequestParams();
        args.Remove("OrganizationId");// E.g remove conflicted fields

        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, args);
        return AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the error. I meant to type `QueryResponse` not `AutoQuery`. Regarding the AutoQuery setup, I did create it myself. Added some examples. Am I not following the recommended setup?

Comment: I used your code to override the verb, but I end up getting the same `FormatException` error. The scenario is this: it's a form to create a record. I have a view model for that form that has the fields needed to create the record along with a few `SelectList` objects to populate dropdowns. If there's a validation error, I repopulate those SelectLists so I can return the view and the user can fix the problem. The issue is that the form is posted to the controller, and when I go to pull the data for the `SelectList`s the form values are all part of the request.

Comment: @Josh AutoQuery works by looking at the QueryString/FormData as well as the typed DTO which is why it can still work with an empty DTO. You likely have a conflict with the QueryString/FormData that's posted to the controller that is being forwarded to AutoQuery to execute. Investigate the StackTrace of the FormatException to see if it provides any hints at which param has the conflict.

Comment: My view model has a field called `OrganizationId` which is nullable. If I post with a null selection I get that error. But it's important to note that I don't want that form field to be part of the AutoQuery...I'd really like to be able to call my `GET` *without* any AutoQuery stuff in this particular case, but I still need to support AutoQuery on that endpoint for my API consumers.

Comment: You're doing some weird forwarding of the MVC HTTP Request from within an MVC Controller where you only want part of the HTTP Request to apply - which IMO is ugly and has expected issues because you're using conflicting fields. Other than passing in a mock IRequest (e.g BasicRequest) to control the Params that the AutoQuery request sees, don't use AutoQuery, just use an explicit Service with a typed DTO that doesn't look at the QueryString.

Comment: Is it possible to support both AutoQuery and direct calls on a single route endpoint? I really don't want to have to maintain an AutoQuery endpoint *and* a strict DTO endpoint when both return the same resources.

Comment: @Josh Not sure what that even means? a single route calls a single service. I don't get why you're not calling the AQ Service directly or change to use non-conflicting fields? AutoQuery should provide rapid development of database-driven services that should be saving you time, if you're running into issues twisting it to support behavior it wasn't designed to do, don't use it, create a custom service you have control of the behavior instead. You may be able to get by with a [Custom AutoQuery impl](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#custom-autoquery-implementations).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97563/discussion-between-josh-and-mythz).

Comment: @Josh I've updated my answer with an example of a Custom AutoQuery impl that removes the conflicted field. If there's still an issue then it's time to ignore AutoQuery and use a Custom Service instead.

Comment: Unfortunately modifying the query like that is probably not feasible. I'd have to remove all possible form post data for all requests in the MVC app that might have to call that API method. I'll work on some non-AutoQuery methods that I can call from the MVC side while leaving the AutoQuery ones available for public consumers that are using the searching.